# One amp volume, multiple guitars

Tags: electric-guitar

When performing, I play several guitars. Volume and response of effects pedals varies from guitar to guitar. Simply adjusting volume changes my sound...any suggestions on how to keep my sound more uniform despite changing guitars?

Comment: You could try using a small mixer, say four channel. One guitar into each channel. That would give you gain, volume and eq separately for each. Output straight into amp - pre or post, your choice!

Comment: Have a volume pedal at the start of the effects chain?

Comment: There are also 'instrument switcher' pedals. An ABY but usually outfitted with separate volumes.

Answer (score 4):

A pedal or three at the start of your effects chain should help. I would look at buffers, boosters, and compressors. For the latter, it’s probably best to have something more transparent and less squashed sounding.

It might be that a buffer is good enough to bring hit your signal chain with the same intensity between guitars, or a compressor set just right and left on. Otherwise you might want to be able to turn on a boost for the quieter guitars, or have a compressor that also slightly boosts the level that you can turn on when needed.

The ultimate precise control would be some kind of MIDI controlled volume or boost pedal that can be configured with a different preset for each guitar. Or a small format multi effect unit like an Eventide H9 where you can select a preset for each guitar that has whatever boost or compression appropriate to match levels.